# Generar matriz en R iterando diagonal +1 y -1

Tags: array, r, bucle-for, bucles, matriz

Quiero generar la matriz mediante bucle for pero no consigo crearla.

-La diagonal son 1.

-El elemento anterior a la diagonal es siempre el mismo número

-El elemento posterior a la diagonal es siempre el mismo número

-El resto de elementos son 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para n=10 (10 filas por ejemplo)

```
n = 10  #dimension del sistema
#Definición de la matriz y el vector del sistema mediante bucles
A = matrix(nrow = n,ncol = n)
for(i in 1:n-1) { }
for(i in 2:n) { }
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero que yo recuerde, solo las matrices cuadradas tienen diagonal principal. El ejemplo que has puesto no es una diagonal cuadrada (es de 5x6)

Answer (score 2):

Basándome en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759503/extracting-off-diagonal-slice-of-large-matrix/11759744#11759744 propongo esta metodología que funciona para matrices cuadradas.

**Primero se crea una matriz auxiliar con las dimensiones deseadas**

```
# dimension
n <- 10

# creamos matriz auxiliar con valores cualesquiera
auxiliar <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow=n)
```

**A continuación, se restan la matriz que indica el numero de fila y la matriz que indica el número de columna.**
Ambas matrices se generan a partir de la matriz auxiliar. Al restar se obtiene una matriz en la que hay valor -1 por encima de la diagonal y 1 por debajo.

```
# restamos las matrices fila y columna obtenidas de la auxiliar
A<- row(auxiliar) - col(auxiliar)
 
# Ahora tenemos valor -1 por encima de la diagonal y valor 1 por debajo
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8    -9
 [2,]    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7    -8
 [3,]    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6    -7
 [4,]    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5    -6
 [5,]    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4    -5
 [6,]    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3    -4
 [7,]    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2    -3
 [8,]    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1    -2
 [9,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    -1
[10,]    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1     0
```

**Por último, basta con sustituir valores:**

```
# sustituimos valores
A[A>1]<-0
A[A<(-1)]<-0

# valor por debajo de la diagonal
A[A==1]<-3

# valor por encima de la diagonal
A[A==(-1)]<-4

# por último ponemos diagonal igual a 1
diag(A)<-1

> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    3    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    3    1    4    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    3    1    4    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    3    1    4    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    3    1    4    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    3    1    4    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    1    4     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    1     4
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3     1
```

Comment: En base a tu respuesta he creado algo similar que me ha dado resultado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @uland si esta respiuesta te ayudó, márcala como correcta para que se cierre la pregunta. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas